# Prove that $2 \alpha/ n< \alpha^2 - t$

Tags: complex-numbers

Hi : I am trying to learn about complex variables so I've been working my way through a book called An Introduction to Complex Analysis and Geometry by John D'angelo. It's a very nice basic book but I'm having trouble with a lot of the exercises. I emailed the author for a solutions manual but it doesn't exist. So what I planned to do was ask questions here when I can't solve the exercise on my own.

I am not a regular member of this list so if I don't follow the proper etiquette please let me know.

My first question is:

For $t - \alpha^2 > 0$, show that there is an $n \in \boldsymbol{N}$, such that
$\frac{2 \alpha}{n} < \alpha^2 - 2$.

I think this question is related to the Archimedean property which is stated as
Proposition 3.2 in the book and says that, given positive real numbers $x$ and
$\epsilon$, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $n \epsilon > x$. Equivalently,
given $y > 0$, there is an $n \in \boldsymbol{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < y$.

Thank you very much to anyone who can help. This is not homework. Just some random
person trying to learn the basics of complex numbers.

Comment: What is $t,\alpha$?

Comment: I think alpha and t are just real numbers.

Comment: If yes, then why is the "complex-numbers" tag added? Also, then if they are real numbers, then you cannot choose $t=2$. However, if they are complex numbers, you can choose $t=2$, and then make $\alpha$ pure imaginary, making the result trivial $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: my fault. I put that because it's from an intro to complex analysis book. If I should change the tag, let me know. Also, as I see the question, it doesn't come out in latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where the $t$ relates here, but you are right that this relies on the Archimedean Property. It can be stated more simply that if $x$ is a real number, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > x$. Here, let $x = \frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2 - 2}$.  Provided $\alpha^2 \neq 2$ (which is what I think you might have meant instead of $t$), then that is a real number, and so there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\frac{2\alpha}{\alpha^2 - 2} < n$$

Dividing both sides by $n$ and multiplying both sides by the denominator on the left gives you the inequality. Keep in mind that you need the denominator to be $> 0$ for the sign of the inequality to remain the same, which is what I think the first statement with $t$ was supposed to say.

Comment: Thank you. The book has t but maybe the author meant 2 instead of t. Just two other questions if you don't mind. On my computer, the latex doesn't show as latex. Also, is there anything I should do as far as closing out the question. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah, maybe you just had a typo and wrote 2 instead of $t$ then in the inequality. Looking at your title that's probably the case. As for the LaTeX rendering, you may need to install a browser extension, I think there are some available for Chrome and Firefox, although I don't recall having to do this. As for closing out the question, we appreciate it if you click a check mark beside a response if you feel it adequately answers the question; it helps let others who may read this know that a solution has been found!

Comment: thanks for the info. I will look for a chrome extension. I checked the answer for people who look at the question in the future. I think it is t but that's okay because I can still use the idea of the answer to answer my question. thank you.